# Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to type <T>. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I tried from hours searching solution for my issue but no post help me out.

I am try to fetch records from database using Linq (Entity Framework 6.0 / MVC 5.0) with library.

```
System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

Complete code below

```
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
     entity.DataFields = "id, stack_trace";
     _list = entities.vsk_error_log
           .OrderBy(entity.Order)
           .Select("New(" + entity.DataFields + ")")
           .Skip(entity.PageSize * entity.PageNumber)
           .Take(entity.PageSize)
           .Cast<vsk_error_log>()
           .ToList();
}
```

But at runtime this result in error

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to
>   type 'VideoKit.framework.vsk_error_log'. LINQ to Entities only
>   supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I know there is casting issue with Select clause but don't know how to fix this casting issue.

**Update No 1:**

If i try to use code as shown below, it will properly fetch data

```
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
     var context = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)entities).ObjectContext;

     lst = context.CreateObjectSet<vsk_error_log>().AsEnumerable().Select("new (id, stack_trace)").Cast<DynamicClass>().ToList();
 }
```

But data retrieved with type

> Generic List of System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicClass

Instead of vsk_error_log

If i try to cast with proper class vsk_error_log instead of DynamicClass then i got error

> Unable to cast object of type 'DynamicClass1' to type
>   'VideoKit.framework.vsk_error_log'.

Data returned shown in screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that instead of `.Cast()` you need to to `.Select( x => new vsk_error_log { y = x.y, z = x.z .... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the entity itself from a dynamic query you have to use the `it` keyword, in stead of `new`:

```
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
     _list = entities.vsk_error_log
           .OrderBy(entity.Order)
           .Select("it") // here "it"
           .Skip(entity.PageSize * entity.PageNumber)
           .Take(entity.PageSize)
           .ToList();
}
```

From your comment I understand that you're trying to get partly filled `vsk_error_log` entities. You can do that using the main part of your query and then convert the `DynamicClass` instances into the entities:

```
var result = new List<vsk_error_log>();

using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
    _list = entities.vsk_error_log
           .OrderBy(entity.Order)
           .Skip(entity.PageSize * entity.PageNumber)
           .Take(entity.PageSize)
           .Select("new (id, stack_trace)");

    foreach(dynamic d in _list)
    {
        result.Add(new vsk_error_log { id = d.id, stack_trace = d.stack_trace } );
    }
}
```

Update:
Complete code which works well with desired output below

```
var _list = new List<vsk_error_log>();
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
    var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)entities).ObjectContext;
    var lst = context.CreateObjectSet<vsk_error_log>()
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select("new(id,stack_trace)")
         .Cast<DynamicClass>()
         .Skip(entity.PageSize * (entity.PageNumber - 1))
         .Take(entity.PageSize)
         .ToList();
         foreach (dynamic d in lst)
         {
             _list.Add(new vsk_error_log { id = d.id, stack_trace = d.stack_trace });
         }
}
```

Comment: Actually new also works but result returns in list of DynamicClass1 instead of proper list object.

Comment: *Don't cast*, is what I'm trying to say. You can get the entity right away.

Comment: Can you update your question with the syntax error and the query giving rise to it?

Comment: I attached screenshot with question of data returned after applying update no 1 code.

Comment: ok "it" working but it returned all columns, what if i need to return selected columns then.

Comment: Then you simply can't cast to `vsk_error_log`. You get a `DynamicClass` and you have to do stuff with that thing.

Comment: Thanks your casting solution worked. i posted full working code on your answer. previous code written on your answer still through error that i mentioned in title.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Cast<type>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't know how to cast the dynamic object you have created into the type you have specified so you will have to do it manually:

```
using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
{
     entity.DataFields = "id, stack_trace";
     _list = entities.vsk_error_log
           .OrderBy(entity.Order)
           .Select("New(" + entity.DataFields + ")")
           .Skip(entity.PageSize * entity.PageNumber)
           .Take(entity.PageSize)
           .Select(x => new vsk_error_log 
           {
               Property1 = x.Property1,
               Property2 = x.Property2,
               //etc...
           })
           .ToList();
}
```